# How to set a specific width for each column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-sheets, google-visualization

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['table'] });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var visualization;
    function drawVisualization() {

        var query = new google.visualization.Query(
        'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18KqoG0VT8c5eaT6IdSzczRPXJX4-CPFfBeImv07n5NA/edit#gid=1324681333');

        query.setQuery('SELECT B, C, D, E, F, H, I, G ');
        query.send(handleQueryResponse);
    }

    function handleQueryResponse(response) {
        if (response.isError()) {
            alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
            return;
        }

        var data = response.getDataTable();

        visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
        visualization.draw(data, { legend: 'bottom' });
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
</script>
<br />
<div id="table">
</div>
```

My english is not good and I'm not a programmer. I just want to size B, C, D, E, F, H, I, G columns differently. thank you. I hope it isn't against the site rules.

Comment: yes, i want to set  a specific width for each column (at least two or three of them)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set column width for google.visualization.DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019300/set-column-width-for-google-visualization-datatable)

Comment: where should i insert that code?

Answer (score 0):

The answer accepted in the question referenced as duplicate doesn't appear to work.
Even when applied to every row vs. the first row as in the answer.

Regardless, you can use a DataView to insert an html `div` into each column.
Include css for the `width` dimensions and assign a class name to each column to be adjusted.

Also recommend using `loader.js` to load google charts vs. the older library `jsapi`.

See following example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawVisualization,
  packages: ['table']
});

var visualization;
function drawVisualization() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query(
    'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18KqoG0VT8c5eaT6IdSzczRPXJX4-CPFfBeImv07n5NA/edit#gid=1324681333'
  );

  query.setQuery('SELECT B, C, D, E, F, H, I, G');
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var data = response.getDataTable();

  // answer from question referenced in comments uses setProperty
  // which doesnt appear to work for "width"
  // even when applied to every row -- not shown here
  // setProperty for style on first cell in table
  data.setProperty(0, 0, 'style', 'background-color: red; width: 500px;');

  // use DataView to customize columns
  // first, load view column indexes
  var viewColumns = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    viewColumns.push(i);
  }

  // next, setup columns to be adjusted
  // column index 1 = second column
  viewColumns[1] = {
    calc: function (dataTable, row) {
      var columnValue = dataTable.getValue(row, 1) || '';
      // class name should match definition in CSS
      return '<div class="column1">' + columnValue + '<div>';
    },
    type: 'string',
    label: data.getColumnLabel(1)
  };

  // column index 3 = fourth column
  viewColumns[3] = {
    calc: function (dataTable, row) {
      var columnValue = dataTable.getValue(row, 3) || '';
      return '<div class="column3">' + columnValue + '<div>';
    },
    type: 'string',
    label: data.getColumnLabel(3)
  };

  // next, create DataView and setColumns
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns(viewColumns);

  // finally, draw chart using view instead of data
  visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
  visualization.draw(view, {
    allowHtml: true
  });
}
```

```css
/* css column definitions */
.column1 {
  width: 150px;
}

.column3 {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table"></div>
```

Comment: sorry i just saw your answer. i just tried thris code but i use this code within a blogger page. so it didn't work.